# How to sync two Mysql database tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, laravel

I have my web based Qoute/Invoice system running at our local server (based on codeigniter). And our website hosted externally (one.com, based on Laravel). lets say i want table products and product families from database local be synced to the remote database in the representitive tables offcourse. Both mysql databases. Also the local database is the "master" so most changes will be made in the local database but i would like the remote database to sync so we can display our producs on the website. the only thing we could change in the remote database is if we display the product or not.

So the question is how i could get those two databases to sync. How could I do a script to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand is you want two database from different servers to be synchronized. You can do that by setting up master-master replication.
[Here's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication) a good step by step documentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS can replicate between MySQL databases locally or remotely over HTTP or HTTPS.  There is an open source version that might be sufficient for your needs.

[SymmetricDS community](http://www.symmetricds.org/)

There is also a professional version if you want to add support.

[SymmetricDS pro](http://www.jumpmind.com/)